# Firefox default download per extension

Tags: firefox

Is there any extension or way to make firefox silently download files to designated locations based on their extensions? I know I can use download managers in order to accomplish this, however, I want to know if there is such way without them, just using firefox+extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick trip to AMO found [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4781).